# Когда будет доступна "Документация" на "SO на русском"?

Tags: обсуждение, документация

Планируется ли создание такого же функционала, как в оригинальном SO? https://stackoverflow.com/documentation

Comment: Зашел только для того, чтобы задать этот вопрос )

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Да, планируется, но точной даты запуска нет.

На данном этапе важно получить отзыв от сообщества о реальном использовании нового раздела, выявить дефекты и исправить их. Наиболее эффективный способ – сделать это на английском языке, так как большинство разработчиков сайта англоговорящие.

С большой вероятностью, документация будет доступна на международных сайтах, как только выйдет из беты (плюс какое–то время на перевод интерфейса пользователя).

Comment: Ничего не изменилось в планах? В смысле, всё ещё планируется или бросили эту идею?
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation

Comment: @XelaNimed Документацию закрыли. Думаю, у нас она тоже не появится с большой вероятностью.

Answer (score 16):

Помню, ещё зимой, при запуске закрытой беты Документации, я спрашивал у Николаса: а нельзя ли и нам такое же получить сразу, в бете?

Но сейчас я смотрю на текущую реализацию документации на SO,

- которая привела к <s>гипер</s>инфляции (т.е. обесцениванию) репутации<sup>*</sup>;
- в которую слишком легко пропихнуть ошибки ([пример](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/65946?draftId=53684)), силами всего лишь одного непрофессионального реп-фермера и одного роборевьюера;
- которая позиционирует себя как Лучшая Документация Всех Времён, но никогда не заменит ни настоящей документации, написанной профессиональными техническими писателями, ни фундаментальных книг;

и надеюсь, что у нас никогда не будет Документации *в таком виде*.

<sup>*</sup> В чате АК попросил объяснить подробнее:

> Совсем другое дело, если гиперинфляция приведёт к каким-либо негативным последствиям. Но тогда и нужно писать о этих негативных последствиях, а не о промежуточных ступенях.

Проблем несколько:

- Репутация дает дополнительные привилегии на сайте. Единолично редактировать, закрывать и даже удалять содержимое. Предполагается, что репутация отражает опыт и вклад участника *в сайт вопросов и ответов*, но с введением Документации это предположение становится неверным.
- Репутация - средство геймификации сайта. Да, нами движет не только искреннее желание делиться знаниями и делать мир лучше, но ещё и любовь к виртуальным числам и пикселям. Гиперинфляция подрывает мотивацию отвечать на вопросы.
- Репутация является косвенным показателем профессионализма. Таким же, как вклад в опенсорс или список прочитанных книг. Предполагаю, что скоро будут популярны запросы по SEDE, показывающие чистую репутацию участника, без учета вклада в Документацию.

Конечно, это пока не гипер-, а просто инфляция. Сотни тысяч репутации по-прежнему что-то значат. Но вот дневной кап репутации уже перестал быть достижением.

Comment: Также разочарован. Неудобный движок, мутные системы голосований и правок. Такое впечатление, что по ошибке соединили худшее из SO и Wiki, вместо лучшего.

Comment: Я уже 1700 репы поднял на Документации! Хочу здесь такое же! =)

Comment: Согласен. Когда еще только анонсировали бету ожидал увидеть первоклассное средство документирования, а получилось весьма второ(третье)сортно. Как я понял цель документации- перехватывать еще больше траффика из поисковиков за счет высокого PR сети SE, и в текущем виде Документация успешно справится с этой задачей, но как средство документирования получилось совсем никак.

Comment: Кстати, совершенно не факт, что у на РуСО случилась бы гиперинфляция: на большом СО это случилось только потому, что количество голосующих превысило все разумные рамки. Такого, что исправил два примера, а потом получаешь кап две недели подряд — точно не было бы.